# app breaks down and cannot use rhc commands

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

My app (rails a ruby-1.9) is currently serving a `503`.

All the `rhc` commands don't work. I cannot even do `rhc ssh <my-app>`.

I tried to restart the app from the web, it gives me this:

```
Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running. 

Unhandled exception reference #78227deaed799856c3c386744c8be9c4: Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running.
```

Comment: Have you tried a 'rhc app-force-stop <app>'?